# Failure in @ExceptionHandler when setting HttpStatus manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to return different error codes with `HttpStatus`es as response when invocation of my endpoint fails.

now I am testing endpoint definition:

```
    @PostMapping("shredding_type/update")
    public void updateShreddingType(
            @RequestBody CdtUpdateReqDTO<ShredTypeGuiDTO> req
    ) throws IOException {
        shreddingTypeCtrl.updateShreddingType(req.getCdt());
    }
```

for `DataIntegrityViolationException` and my exception handler looks like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandlingAspect {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    private ResponseStatusException handleException(Exception ex) {
        OperationCtx ctx = OpCtxHolder.getCurrReqCtx();
        ctx.setStatusCode(400);
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

        if ("static GUI".equals(ctx.getSystemName()))
            status = createCodeForGUI(ex);

        return new ResponseStatusException(status);
    }

    private HttpStatus createCodeForGUI(Exception ex) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

        if (ex instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException)
            status = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;

        return status;
    }
}
```

and I'm still getting `HttpResponse` of status code `500` in my angular app.

this is the stacktrace I get when violating that constrain:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3174)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3688)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at com.nws.vedica.dbs.dao.ShreddingTypeDAO.getAllTypes(ShreddingTypeDAO.java:51)
    at com.nws.vedica.dbs.dao.ShreddingTypeDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$460d869e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "shredding_type_shreddingtype_key"
  Detail: Key (shreddingtype)=(N2) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 139 common frames omitted
2019-10-25_12:05:35.473 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failure in @ExceptionHandler private org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException com.nws.vedica.aop.ErrorHandlingAspect.handleException(java.lang.Exception)  sys$reqId: pYfaKFF; statusCode: 400; ip: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; userId: static GUI; epUri: /api/KDMS/shredding_type/update; sys$systemName: static GUI 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.lang.Throwable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException["mostSpecificCause"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1297)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException["mostSpecificCause"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

notice the `Failure in @ExceptionHandler private org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException..` part. I think this is the reason why setting `HttpStatus` manually fails but can not figure why it is.

What can be wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually changing the HTTP status code. You're just putting one into your `ResponseStatusException`. But that doesn't magically change the response code.

If you include a `HttpServletResponse` parameter, you can set the code with `response.setStatus(400)`. If the code is always the same, you don't need the respose, and can annotate the handler method with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)`.

However in your case the correct response code is `500`, since your server did something wrong (5XX codes) and not the client (4XX codes).

Comment: that's correct! what other mechanism would you use to signal the error to the client?

Comment: @greengold what do you mean by mechanism?

Comment: how to tell celient what has happend

Comment: @greengold well the HTTP status code is a standard, so unless you have reasons not to use it (?), that's what you should use. But in this case the client shouldn't care what happened, since your code failed to handle gracefully this situation. Depending on what you're doing, you should either write the server code so that you can't get duplicates, or write logic to allow the client to retry the operation (if possible).